# Does きれいにして have a difference nuance compared to きれいで here?

Tags: readings, て-form, adjectives

> いつも洒落できれいにしてて品がある

My understand is akin to "She's always fashionable,pretty and polished

However, why is きれいにしてて here used over just きれい? What does different nuance does it provide?

Comment: Is she merely pretty or does she make herself look attractive?

Comment: I think she's just pretty

Comment: I think the sentence is suggesting that she's more than just pretty.  I believe the sentence suggests that she puts some effort into her appearance.

Comment: It's いつも**お**洒落で... no?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

Ignoring the matter of the auxiliary いて,
I think you should consider how the following would sound different:

- きれいだ
- きれいになった
- きれいにした

Each has a different nuance.

The first, きれいだ, just means "she's pretty".

きれいになった  means "she became pretty"

きれいにした means "she made [herself] pretty".  The key is that there is always someone doing the する; it's deliberate and intentional.  Otherwise, なった would make better sense or you could go with the first sentence.  As suggested by @chocolate, this expression is rather suggestive of putting on make-up and doing up one's hair.  Perhaps a bit more colloquially we could say, *she prettied herself up* (conveying the same nuance).

So, in your case, the use of する shows that "she", whoever she is, did something to make something (perhaps herself) pretty.  So, there's an added layer of nuance here that the *speaker* is trying to convey that would not be there if it were just きれいだ.

The addition of いて adds a further layer of nuance that she not only made herself pretty, but that her effort to make herself pretty persists even now.

None of this suggests that, without effort, she wouldn't be pretty.  Rather, it just suggests that she tends to her appearance.

If we look at the phrases, we move from someone who's not merely fashionable, but also someone who minds her appearance and is a rather *refined* individual (品がある).

This feels like an arc of deliberate and conscious choices.  Merely saying きれいで, would not match this pattern of deliberate choices (since just merely being pretty isn't a choice).

Comment: 「（女性が）いつもきれいにしてる」って聞くと、いつもちゃんとお化粧してるってことだろうな～って想像しますが、わたしだけでしょうか。（もちろん髪もきれいにしてるでしょうけど）